# YUI2- How remove some html elements without the content inside?

Tags: javascript, yui, yui2

How remove some html elements without the content inside?(YUI2)

Simple Example-remove **span.exclass** element without content+insert white-space for keep words separate:

**input:**

```
<br/>&nbsp;<span class="just"></span>
<div>&nbsp;
textetxt <span class="exclass">texttetx</span>texttext
</div>&nbsp;
<br/>
<p>&nbsp;<span class="just"></span>
textetxt <span class="exclass">texttetx</span>texttext
</p>&nbsp;
```

**output:**

```
<br/>&nbsp;<span class="just"></span>
<div>&nbsp;
textetxt texttetx texttext
</div>&nbsp;
<br/>
<p>&nbsp;<span class="just"></span>
textetxt texttetx texttext
</p>&nbsp;
```

In Jquery it should be if I not wrong- but in yui2 i don't know:

```
$('span.exclass').each(function(){
  $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
});
```

Thanks,
Yosef

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elems = YAHOO.util.Dom.getElementsByClassName('exclass', 'span');
for (var el, i = elems.length; i-- && (el = elems[i]);) {
  el.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(el.innerHTML + ' '), el);
}​
```

​